# How to prevent content jumping in framer-motion animation when transitioning between two pages

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have essentially the following setup:

```
<AnimatePresence initial={false}>
  {value ? (
    <motion.div>
      {/* Page 1 content */}
    </motion.div>
  ) : (
    <motion.div>
      {/* Page 2 content */}
    </motion.div>
  )}
</AnimatePresence>
```

When `value` changes from `true` to `false`, I want page 1 to slide out to the left while *at the same time* page 2 slides in from the right. This is very similar to how slideshows work, or page transitions on iOS apps.

I have a simple example set up on CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-4kin7k?file=/src/App.js:272-1064. What happens when I toggle `value` is that the pages slide to the left as expected, but because the pages are different heights, they cause the content under them to jump down. Also, since both pages are rendered at the same time during the animation, the first page causes the 2nd page to render below it as well, so when the animation completes, page 2 jumps up.

[image]

How can I do this sort of animation without the content jumping around? Ideally, I want:

- Page 2 to appear to the right of page 1, not rendered below it.

  - This will prevent page 2 from jumping up when page 1 unmounts after its slide out animation completes.
- The height of the container to animate to the height of page 2.

  - This will prevent the content under the pages from jumping down when the animation starts.

Answer (score 5):

## Update :

add `mode="wait"` in your AnimationPresence component

```js
<AnimatePresence mode="wait" initial={false}> 
    <motion.div>....</motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this problem too. To make it so that there is no delay, and you don't have to wait until the element leaves like the other answers have, you simply have to position the elements on top of each other.

I've found the most elegant solution is to simply add a `position: absolute` css style to your motion.div component. You can then wrap the outer AnimatePresence component with a div that has a `position: relative` style and a set height so that it looks correct.

The structure should be like so:

```
<div style={{position: "relative"}}>
    <AnimatePresence> 
         <motion.div style={{position: "absolute"}}>...</motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
</div>
```

here is your modified codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lumiere-7vwb8n?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with `layoutId` you can simply append the current pathname to the id.

```
const pathname = usePathname();


return (
    <motion.div
        layoutId={`${pathname}-some-id`}
        transition={{ ease: "circOut", duration: 0.5 }}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm running out of time to dig into finding a technical answer, but I used this [Framer-Motion Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-gallery-pqvx3?from-embed) as a guide.

Steps:

1. Wrapped animate presence in a div.
2. Added Flex and fixed height to max height of largest component in animate presence.
3. Added duration of 0.5 to exit animations
4. Added delay of 0.5 to allow exit animations to complete

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxFRq.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2umtW.png)

Here's the sandbox I used:
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-forest-5m1p7x?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `exitBeforeEnter` property to the `AnimatePresence` component, which should fix your issue!

Something like this :

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter initial={false}> 
    <motion.div>....</motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of framer, `mode="popLayout"` can also be used on AnimatePresence. This will not delay animations of `<motion.div>` children as `in mode="wait"`.

```
<AnimatePresence mode="popLayout"> 
    <motion.div>....</motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```

https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/###mode